# Webp images with transparent backgrounds appearing black in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-11, webp

I have a large amount of WEBP images stored in a folder. When viewing this folder in Windows Explorer, the WEBPs have their transparent backgrounds rendered as black and blocky.

[image: image of blocky background]

However, when viewing these files in any other program they look identical to their PNG counterparts.

Is this an issue with File Explorer or can it be fixed by installing a new WEBP codec or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the thumbnails cache. Press **WINDOWS + R** to open run command, type cleanmgr and press **ENTER**. Select c: drive and click ok. In the list select thumbnails and click ok, confirm that you want to permanently exclude the files and wait. See if anything has changed, maybe you have to restart the computer.